# Do students need to wait a year to join university in Canada?

Tags: university, canada

I am an Indian and my son is going to complete high school (+2) in March 2020.
I am planning to apply for engineering/computer science for my son in any university/college in Canada.

Now, I come to know that the application end date is January 2020 for the courses starting in September 2020.

In India, school final exams happen in March/April and results are published in May every year.
My son will get mark sheets, transfer certificate and all documents in May 2020, after completing his high school (+2) exams. When applying for a college/university in India (which opens in July), we need to submit above mentioned documents, because whether we are going to get the college seat or not is **based on those documents/grade/marks**.

So, do I have to wait to apply for him in Jan. 2021, for the courses starting in Sept. 2021?

In other words, do the students need to wait year to study in Canada?

**As the schools in Canada ends in July/August**, how they are applying to university/college?

Comment: Why are you applying? Shouldn't your son be applying himself?

Comment: Your question seems just target a specific people as indian student wants to join a college or university specifically in Ontario, CA. I'm not sure, this question could be answered here or not cause it depends on condition of those specific people.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, I edited to make this questions as more common. How the local students handling this situation?

Comment: @NiceGuy Still it's not clear. What do you mean by saying: "I am wondering, as the schools in Canada ends in july/august, how they are applying to university/college?" You mean what documents are needed to apply or which site they use or something else? If you are looking for these kind of information I believe admission office of universities are the best resouces.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer, I added details in Edit part

Comment: @user2768, "I am indian" is relevant because start and end months for academic year is different in India and Canada. In India it is June-May and In Canada it is Sep-Aug.

Comment: @NiceGuy I think it pretty much depends on university's rules. Again, I reiterate my argument: The best bet for you is to contact admission office of the university that you want to apply to get help from them. Even different universities may have different rules...

Comment: @user2768: _Why are you applying?_ :  This is the **cultural difference**, I hope no south-indians will ask this question. To clarify, We both will discuss, fill forms, apply together or spiliting tasks between us. We(south-Indians) don't see this approach as the son is incapable but an emotional attachment _( of we than I )_ which made me phrase this question like that.

Comment: What does "high school (+2)" mean?

Comment: I edited your post to make it more readable. Instead of adding edits at the bottom, please edit the whole question as you go to incorporate necessary information. FYI, I'm not aware of any Canadian high schools that finish in July/August, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Canadian Students typically apply before they have received their diploma, and acceptance will be conditional on graduation. They send their notes transcript up to this point and any relevant documents. Please note that many programs have multiple admission rounds and applying during the summer is possible in that case. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Based on other answers, comments and my own research, I found the below.

From **University of Waterloo** website...

> **Sending your documents**
>
> Once you've applied, there are a couple of
> things you need to do before we can make an admission decision.
>
> You must submit your transcripts and documents (outlined below) by our
> document deadline.
> You can upload **unofficial** documents so that we can review your
> application and make a decision.
>
> **If** you receive an offer of admission, we will require **official versions** of the documents. Your **conditional** offer of admission will provide details. We cannot make a decision if
> we do not have all your documents, e.g., transcripts, English language
> test scores (if required), Admission Information Form (if required for
> your program). **If your mid-term grades are not available** by the
> deadline, please submit them **as soon as possible.**

and

> **Students from India:**
>
> Please arrange for your Grade 10 board examination results and Grade
> 12 **predicted** examination results to be sent to the Office of the
> Registrar.
>
> If you receive an offer of admission to Waterloo, we will also require
> your official Grade 12 board examination results.

**Related Useful links:**

https://uwaterloo.ca/future-students/admissions/sending-your-grades

https://www.ontariocolleges.ca/en/apply/important-dates

https://uwaterloo.ca/future-students/admissions/application-deadlines

https://uwaterloo.ca/future-students/admissions/official-documents

http://www.electronicinfo.ca/deadlines

https://www.ontario.ca/page/study-ontario-international-students#section-0

https://uwaterloo.ca/future-students/admissions/admission-requirements/computer-eng/international-system/indian-system/

Answer (score 1):

The application deadline is January, yet your son won't receive grades until May. Perhaps your son can apply with his predicted grades, rather than his actual grades, and the university can make an offer conditional on him obtaining his predicted grades.

---

<sup>I'm unfamiliar with the particularities of the Canadian system and my answer is based upon systems elsewhere.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am looking for Canada specific info.

Comment: @NiceGuy Just check whether this applies in Canada.

Comment: I found more useful information here - https://uwaterloo.ca/future-students/admissions/admission-requirements/computer-eng/international-system/indian-system/

Comment: @NiceGuy - if your own research has given you a better answer than anybody else has posted so far; please don't hesitate to post your own findings as an answer (and accept it yourself). Doing so helps people in the future, who have the same problem as you.